# Outlook inline image insert

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When creating or replying to an email in Outlook 3013, is there a way to inline-insert an image without having to go to the trouble of "Pop Out" -> "INSERT" tab ->"Pictures" -> (find image in folder) -> "Insert" Button ?

If you drag and drop into the new message it attaches it as a file.

**Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert instead of attach when drag-and-drop ing?**

Ive tried the obvious like holding shift / ctrl / alt while dragging but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such a keyboard shortcut to drag and drop image to an email, see [Keyboard shortcuts for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd). The only keyboard shortcut can be used here is Alt, N, P (press one by one) which is used to open the insert picture dialogue box.

If you need to insert many pictures into the body of a message, you may consider trying the steps below as a workaround:

1. Open Word, go to Insert > Pictures, select all the images you need in the email (you may press Ctrl when selecting multiple images), click OK to insert all the pictures into the Word document.
2. Open Outlook, composing the email, switch to the Word document, copy(Ctrl+C) the image you want to insert, press Ctrl+V to paste it into the message body.